# identyifying inet-packet headers

Tags: c, sockets, packet

so example

```
switch(ether_type)
    case 0x800: //ip header next
        switch (ip_Protocol)
            case 6: // tcp header next
                switch tcp_dst_or_src_port:
                    case 80: // http header next
                        so what tells me now whats next ??
```

just found out that in this example at case 80 the "content_type" filed would tell me whats next .. ex. a jpeg or whatever

sometimes i see 3 or 2 other headers for example on top of http in wireshark

and general question is it always possible to identify every header for example on top of udp or tcp

i want to make an app that works like this switch case example.. beginning at ether header

**ok once again its not http or a specific protocol i wanna know if i can do it that similar to that example with every protocol with switch and memcmp for example to work my way up next and next ?????????????????????**

Comment: What's your question? Yes, TCP port 80 traffic is *usually* HTTP. While the lower layers are very deterministic, the upper layer Wireshark dissectors often use fuzzy heuristics to determine how to parse the data.

Comment: ahm ye if they use fuzzy heuristics i would like to know how that works... i mean i i just found out that in http -> "content type"<- would tell me whats next thats what i mean is there always something like a number or byte sequence wich exactly identifys the hext header ?

Comment: HTTP headers are text. After that is finally the actual payload.

Comment: Jonathon Reinhart just found content_type field wich is ascii text so the next would be ex. strcmp(http_conten_type, "image/png\r\n") thats also what i wanted to know anyway                                                                                                                     PLS YOU CAN REMOVE THIS QUESTION